# 'mail' use problem from command line

Tags: command-line, email

I didn't have mail installed before, so I've did it using:

```
apt-get install mailutils
```

After that I've tried to send a mail with this command:

```
mail -s "Ssubjects" name@host.com
```

But I see just this error message:

```
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

anyway I can't understand what is the problem. Should I configure something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [mail: cannot send message: process exited with a non-zero status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185365/mail-cannot-send-message-process-exited-with-a-non-zero-status)

Try:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix

as proposed in the answer.